# How to plot implicit function using ezplot in octave?

Tags: octave

newTheta Vector is of size 4

```
  -6.3702
   0.5712
   0.2067
   0.3877
```

It can plot:

```
ezplot("-6.3702 + 0.5712*x + 0.2067*y + 0.3877*x*y", [-10 10]);
```

[image: see figure]

But the problem occurs when I pass values of newTheta vector into the equation.
Octave can plot the following command:

```
ezplot(@(x,y) newTheta(1) + newTheta(2)*x + newTheta(3)*y, [-10 10]);
```

[image: see figure]

But does not plot this command:

```
ezplot(@(x,y) newTheta(1) + newTheta(2)*x + newTheta(3)*y + newTheta(4)*x *y, [-10 10])
```

[image: the graph is blank]

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a dot, `.*`, when multiplying for vectorization because `x` and `y` are vectors. This should work:

```
newTheta  = [-6.3702
   0.5712
   0.2067
   0.3877];

ezplot(@(x,y) newTheta(1) + newTheta(2)*x + newTheta(3)*y + newTheta(4)*x .*y, [-10 10])
```

[image]